# Cap deploy:cold failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, rvm1-capistrano3

Hi I am trying to deploy my rails application using capistrano but facing the following issue:
Log:

```
triggering load callbacks
  * 2016-04-15 15:18:25 executing `deploy:cold'
  * 2016-04-15 15:18:25 executing `deploy:update'
 ** transaction: start
  * 2016-04-15 15:18:25 executing `deploy:update_code'
    triggering before callbacks for `deploy:update_code'
  * 2016-04-15 15:18:25 executing `sidekiq:quiet'
  * executing "if [ -d /home/stockbucks/apps/notification_app/current ] && [ -f /home/stockbucks/apps/notification_app/shared/pids/sidekiq.pid ] && kill -0 `cat /home/stockbucks/apps/notification_app/shared/pids/sidekiq.pid`> /dev/null 2>&1; then cd /home/stockbucks/apps/notification_app/current && bundle exec sidekiqctl quiet /home/stockbucks/apps/notification_app/shared/pids/sidekiq.pid ; else echo 'Sidekiq is not running'; fi"
    servers: ["128.100.183.213"]
    [128.100.183.213] executing command
 ** [out :: 128.100.183.213] Sidekiq is not running
 ** [out :: 128.100.183.213] 
    command finished in 1000ms
    updating the cached checkout on all servers
    executing locally: "git ls-remote git@bitbucket.org:imprikalabs/notification_app master"
    command finished in 3455ms
  * executing "if [ -d /home/stockbucks/apps/notification_app/shared/cached-copy ]; then cd /home/stockbucks/apps/notification_app/shared/cached-copy && git fetch -q origin && git fetch --tags -q origin && git reset -q --hard dd959a5544b08371f994a5127485f3fe07d04ced && git clean -q -d -x -f; else git clone -q -b master git@bitbucket.org:imprikalabs/notification_app /home/stockbucks/apps/notification_app/shared/cached-copy && cd /home/stockbucks/apps/notification_app/shared/cached-copy && git checkout -q -b deploy dd959a5544b08371f994a5127485f3fe07d04ced; fi"
    servers: ["128.100.183.213"]
    [128.100.183.213] executing command
    command finished in 7701ms
    copying the cached version to /home/stockbucks/apps/notification_app/releases/20160415094838
  * executing "cp -RPp /home/stockbucks/apps/notification_app/shared/cached-copy /home/stockbucks/apps/notification_app/releases/20160415094838 && (echo dd959a5544b08371f994a5127485f3fe07d04ced > /home/stockbucks/apps/notification_app/releases/20160415094838/REVISION)"
    servers: ["128.100.183.213"]
    [128.100.183.213] executing command
    command finished in 1522ms
  * 2016-04-15 15:18:39 executing `deploy:finalize_update'
    triggering before callbacks for `deploy:finalize_update'
  * 2016-04-15 15:18:39 executing `deploy:assets:symlink'
  * executing "rm -rf /home/stockbucks/apps/notification_app/releases/20160415094838/public/assets && mkdir -p /home/stockbucks/apps/notification_app/releases/20160415094838/public && mkdir -p /home/stockbucks/apps/notification_app/shared/assets && ln -s /home/stockbucks/apps/notification_app/shared/assets /home/stockbucks/apps/notification_app/releases/20160415094838/public/assets"
    servers: ["128.100.183.213"]
    [128.100.183.213] executing command
    command finished in 623ms
  * 2016-04-15 15:18:40 executing `bundle:install'
  * executing "cd /home/stockbucks/apps/notification_app/releases/20160415094838 && bundle install --gemfile /home/stockbucks/apps/notification_app/releases/20160415094838/Gemfile --path /home/stockbucks/apps/notification_app/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test"
    servers: ["128.100.183.213"]
    [128.100.183.213] executing command
    command finished in 1594ms
  * 2016-04-15 15:18:41 executing `whenever:update_crontab'
  * executing "cd /home/stockbucks/apps/notification_app/releases/20160415094838 && bundle exec whenever --update-crontab notification_app --set environment=production --roles db"
    servers: ["128.100.183.213"]
    [128.100.183.213] executing command
 ** [out :: 128.100.183.213] [write] crontab file updated
 ** [out :: 128.100.183.213] 
    command finished in 1348ms
  * executing "chmod -R -- g+w /home/stockbucks/apps/notification_app/releases/20160415094838 && rm -rf -- /home/stockbucks/apps/notification_app/releases/20160415094838/public/system && mkdir -p -- /home/stockbucks/apps/notification_app/releases/20160415094838/public/ && ln -s -- /home/stockbucks/apps/notification_app/shared/system /home/stockbucks/apps/notification_app/releases/20160415094838/public/system && rm -rf -- /home/stockbucks/apps/notification_app/releases/20160415094838/log && ln -s -- /home/stockbucks/apps/notification_app/shared/log /home/stockbucks/apps/notification_app/releases/20160415094838/log && rm -rf -- /home/stockbucks/apps/notification_app/releases/20160415094838/tmp/pids && mkdir -p -- /home/stockbucks/apps/notification_app/releases/20160415094838/tmp/ && ln -s -- /home/stockbucks/apps/notification_app/shared/pids /home/stockbucks/apps/notification_app/releases/20160415094838/tmp/pids"
    servers: ["128.100.183.213"]
    [128.100.183.213] executing command
    command finished in 424ms
    triggering after callbacks for `deploy:finalize_update'
  * 2016-04-15 15:18:43 executing `deploy:symlink_config'
  * executing "ln -nfs /home/stockbucks/apps/notification_app/shared/config/mongoid.yml /home/stockbucks/apps/notification_app/releases/20160415094838/config/mongoid.yml"
    servers: ["128.100.183.213"]
    [128.100.183.213] executing command
    command finished in 441ms
    triggering after callbacks for `deploy:update_code'
  * 2016-04-15 15:18:44 executing `deploy:assets:precompile'
    triggering before callbacks for `deploy:assets:precompile'
  * 2016-04-15 15:18:44 executing `deploy:assets:update_asset_mtimes'
  * executing "[ -e '/home/stockbucks/apps/notification_app/shared/assets/.sprockets-manifest*' ] && cat /home/stockbucks/apps/notification_app/shared/assets/.sprockets-manifest* || echo"
    servers: ["128.100.183.213"]
    [128.100.183.213] executing command
    command finished in 317ms
  * executing "cd -- /home/stockbucks/apps/notification_app/releases/20160415094838 && RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets bundle exec rake assets:precompile"
    servers: ["128.100.183.213"]
    [128.100.183.213] executing command
    command finished in 12288ms
  * executing "ls -1 /home/stockbucks/apps/notification_app/shared/assets/.sprockets-manifest* | wc -l"
    servers: ["128.100.183.213"]
    [128.100.183.213] executing command
    command finished in 444ms
  * executing "ls /home/stockbucks/apps/notification_app/shared/assets/.sprockets-manifest*"
    servers: ["128.100.183.213"]
    [128.100.183.213] executing command
    command finished in 426ms
*** [whenever:update_crontab] rolling back
  * executing "ls -x /home/stockbucks/apps/notification_app/releases"
    servers: ["128.100.183.213"]
    [128.100.183.213] executing command
    command finished in 391ms
  * executing "cd /home/stockbucks/apps/notification_app/releases/20160415073646 && bundle exec whenever --update-crontab notification_app --set environment=production --roles db"
    servers: ["128.100.183.213"]
    [128.100.183.213] executing command
 ** [out :: 128.100.183.213] [write] crontab file updated
 ** [out :: 128.100.183.213] 
    command finished in 992ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /home/stockbucks/apps/notification_app/releases/20160415094838; true"
    servers: ["128.100.183.213"]
    [128.100.183.213] executing command
    command finished in 496ms
failed: "rvm_path=$HOME/.rvm $HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell 'default' -c 'ls /home/stockbucks/apps/notification_app/shared/assets/.sprockets-manifest*'" on 128.100.183.213
```

Comment: Would help if you posted full log.

Comment: failed: "rvm_path=$HOME/.rvm $HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell 'default' -c 'ls /home/stockbucks/apps/notification_app/shared/assets/.sprockets-manifest*'" on 128.100.183.213 @